# Sequence generation using pytorch RNN

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, sequence-generators

I asked this over at the pytorch discussion forum as well ([link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/rnn-module-for-sequence-generation/9346)) but I figured I'd ask here in case it gets more traction.

I trained a model using pytorch's `nn.RNN()` module by feeding it batches of sequences (of varying `seq_len`) and properly padding when sequences in the batch were of different lengths.

I'm now trying to generate sequences using the trained RNN model.  I make a sequence of length one containing the index of my `GO_TOKEN` and feed that to my trained RNN. Unfortunately what I'm getting back are all 0s.  Has anyone done this before?

Some code in case that helps:

```
class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,  
                 inputs_vocab_size,
                 embedding_dim,
                 out_units=128, 
                 hidden_size=128,
                 nlayers=1,
                 num_directions=1,
                 dropout=0.1):

        super(Model, self).__init__()

        ...

        self.encoder = nn.Embedding(inputs_vocab_size, embedding_dim).cuda()
        self.rnn = nn.RNN(embedding_dim, hidden_size, nlayers, dropout=0.5)
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(hidden_size * num_directions, inputs_vocab_size)

        ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not enough information to answer this question. For seq2seq, please see some simplified code at http://github.com/hunkim/PyTorchZeroToAll.